# Why ContentPart is not in ContentItem?

Tags: orchardcms

Why an fieldless ContentPart is not included in a ContentItem?

Here are code from Migrations.cs:

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ImageDescribedPartRecord", 
                table => table.ContentPartRecord());

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
                "ImageDescribedPart",
                cpd => cpd.WithField(
                    "Image",
                    b => b
                             .OfType("MediaPickerField")
                             .WithSetting("MediaPickerFieldSettings.Required", "false")));

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(
                "PlantPicture",
                cfg => cfg
                           .WithPart("ImageDescribedPart")
                           .WithPart("CommonPart", p => p.WithSetting("OwnerEditorSettings.ShowOwnerEditor", "false"))
                           .WithPart("BodyPart")
                           .WithPart("TitlePart")
                           .WithPart("AutoroutePart"
                                     , builder =>
                                       builder
                                           .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "false")
                                           .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "true")
                                           .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{Name:'Container', Pattern: '{Content.Container.Path}/images/{Content.Slug}', Description: 'apgii/taxon/sub-taxon/images/title'}]")
                                           .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex", "0"))
                           .WithPart("ContainablePart")
                           .Creatable(true)
                    // todo: The following doesn't work. Make it work.
                           .WithSetting("BodyPartSettings.FlavorDefault", "text") 
                           );
```

Here are code for the ContentPart:

```
public class ImageDescribedPart : ContentPart<ImageDescribedPartRecord>{

    }

 public class ImageDescribedPartRecord :ContentPartRecord {}
```

The following code from a driver

```
IContentQuery<ContentItem> query = _contentManager
     .Query(VersionOptions.Published)
    .Join<CommonPartRecord>()
    .Where(cr => cr.Container.Id == container.Id);
var items = query.Slice(0, 10).ToList();

IEnumerable<Zulatm.WebPlants.Models.ImageDescribedPart> firstImages = items.AsPart<ImageDescribedPart>();

Logger.Debug("Items count: {0}", items.Count());
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++) {
    Logger.Debug("Item {0}: {1}", i, items[i].As<TitlePart>().Title);

}
Logger.Debug("Images count: {0}",firstImages.Count());
```

Returns the following

```
2012-12-07 16:28:45,616 [35] TaxonomyNodePartDriver - Items count: 2
2012-12-07 16:28:45,617 [35] TaxonomyNodePartDriver - Item 0: Test
2012-12-07 16:28:45,619 [35] TaxonomyNodePartDriver - Item 1: test img 2
2012-12-07 16:28:45,619 [35] TaxonomyNodePartDriver - Images count: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You "cast" the item to a part and store it as an IEnumerable. I wonder how this doesn't cause a compile error, because this is wrong.

Most possibly the root of your problems is that if you plan to use a part directly by "casting", the part should have a corresponding driver (can be empty).

Comment: That is valid to cast to a Part. See a method ContentExtension.AsPart<T>(this IEnumerable<ContentItem> items). Also a part doesn't require a driver to query it. It requires a correct filter. Please see my answer below.

Comment: You're right on that one, I've overseen that item is in plural there. I apologize for the confusion.
However I'm still right with the answer to your question: I've spoken about "casting" (the As<>() method) and yes, you do need a driver for that if you attach the part from migrations as you've presented. Thus my answer is correct even if you've found another solution. I don't understand why you voted it down.

Comment: @Piedone is right - initially you've described the part in migrations only. In that case this answer is perfectly ok - there was a driver missing. You took a different approach, ok, but that's not a reason to downvote a valid answer. Also, please keep in mind that when using `ActivatingFilter` you won't be able to remove that part from admin UI.

Comment: @Artjom Part requires a driver to be there. It's a good practice. If your part does nothing (does not hold any data and is not used for display) you could as well attach your field to a part called the same as your type without the need for filter. `ActivatingFilter` is a shorthand to use if you need some part to be attached to a particular type at all times. It is **not** required for every part and should not be used every time.

Comment: @Piedone. Thank you for your comment and answer. Yes, I didn't think about a driver of the part to be added. About the vote. I didn't do it.

Comment: @Piotr, thanks too! I will try to add a driver to a part. Though it seems strange to me that to yield a part in a type I need to add a driver for it.

Comment: @Piotr I have tried a driver without *ActivatingFilter*. I created *ImageDescribedPartDriver* driver and removed ActivatingFilter addding in the handler. So in order a part to be welded I've added the ActivatingFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The problem was there was no Filter added in Handler. Have added ActivatorFilter:

```
public ImageDescribedHandler (IRepository<ImageDescribedPartRecord> repository,      INavigationManager navigationManager)
{
    Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<ImageDescribedPart>("PlantPicture"));
}
```

Also deleted the line for creating a table.